# Android reusing GWT RPC backend without AppEngine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt-rpc

I have been developing GWT application for a while and I'm trying to port my app to Android.  I'm very new to Android but it seems that the ADT share many similarities with GWT so the learning curve might not be very steep.

There's what I read from GPE 2.4

> Android and GWT clients that are capable of talking to the same App
>   Engine backend using the same RPC code and business logic.

It would be great to share the same backend which I spent a hell lot of effort in design and implementation.  However, I'm not using AppEngine and impossible to switch to it either.  I'm wondering if the Android app can still share the same RPC structure with GWT without using AppEngine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use http-dispatch. It is the adapted gwt-dispatch framework which can be used on Android platform. Http-dispatch uses default binary serialization so it works from the box for many types of objects. Currently it is in alpha but you can try http://code.google.com/p/http-dispatch/

Answer (score 1):

If you're still in need of a solution, check out GWT-SyncProxy (Disclaimer, I recently joined the project). I just put out a 0.4 release that has an Android Library that allows you to make GWT RPC calls from Android (or Java standalone apps using the regular library).

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/.

The library can utilize Android accounts if you do switch to GAE, but it's definitely not required.